# How is average calculated in the aggregations for azure app service plan metrics (specifically for SocketOutboundAll)?

Tags: azure, metrics, azure-appservice

I am looking at the metrics for a app service plan (App Service plan > metrics) specifically the SocketOutboundAll over the last 4 hours. When I apply the aggregations on the metric I get values that don't seem intuitive to me.

Example:
If I look at the **count** of SocketOutboundAll I get a value almost always consistently at 1. However if I choose average(**avg**) I get values in a higher range 40-50.

I would have though this avg value should have been ~1 (give or take the odd fluctuation). How does this average work i.e. what calculation is it doing internally to come up with that number?